# ELY06017: Usage of BASIC and OIDC authentication in one ear (Widfly Elytron)

Tags: elytron, wildfly-26

I am having an application (ear) hosting those services in *Wildfly 26.1.3*:

*myapp.ear* :

- myservlet.war (secured with BASIC authentication in web.xml using the ApplicationDomain)
- myRest.war (secured with OIDC authentication using wildfly:elytron-oidc-client:1.0 + keycloak)
- myServices.jar (containing ejbs + entities)

Before activating the OIDC security BASIC authentication worked fine. After successfully activating the OIDC security the BASIC authentication does no longer work.
It fails with HTTP 500 Internal server error:

```
org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticationException: ELY06017: HTTP authentication is required but no authentication mechansims are available.

at:
org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator$AuthenticationExchange.authenticate(HttpAuthenticator.java:317)
```

The documentation claims that the OIDC subsystem automatically creates a security domain. And it looks like that the "old" domain is no longer available.
Any idea how I can activate the old existing standard security domain "ApplicationDomain"?

Here is the OIDC config from standalone.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron-oidc-client:1.0">
        <secure-deployment name="myRest.war">
            <auth-server-url>https://auth.sample.com/auth</auth-server-url>
            <ssl-required>ALL</ssl-required>
            <realm>myRealm</realm>
            <resource>myResource</resource>
            <credential name="secret" secret="mySecret"/>
        </secure-deployment>
    </subsystem>
```

The config (standalone.xml) for the BASIC authentication is standard. And simply activated in web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

When I disable the OIDC configuration from standalone.xml the BASIC authentication works. If I enable the OIDC subsystem the OIDC authentication works fine, but BASIC authentication for my servlet fails.

Thanks!